# Incrementing multiple variables in PHP For loop

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I have a code that separates first from last names, that I am using on a form that could have up to ten names.  Right now I have simply replicated the code multiple times, manually updating the number, but figure there has to be a way to loop this function.

The basic code is:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name2'])) {
    $name2 = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['name2']));
    $parser = new HumanNameParser_Parser($name2);
    $fname2 = $parser->getFirst();
    $lname2 = $parser->getLast();
}
```

As the fname and lname variables are used elsewhere I need to stick with the naming.

I was thinking to use a For:

```
for ($i=2; $i <= 6; $i++)
{
    if (!empty($_POST['name($i)'])) {
        $name($i) = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['name($i)']));
        $parser = new HumanNameParser_Parser($name($i));
        $fname($i) = $parser->getFirst();
        $lname($i) = $parser->getLast();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

But I am having a tough time figuring what I should actually use for the ($i) in my example.  I tried .$i and [$i] but keep getting errors.  And not sure if the way I should code it in the $_POST would be different than the variable $name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the $_POST variable you can use `$_POST['name' . $i]` and for the name variable you can just replace it with `${'name' . $i};`

so it will be like this

```
for ($i=2; $i <= 6; $i++)
{
if (!empty($_POST['name' . $i])) {
    ${'name' . $i} = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['name' . $i]));
    $parser = new HumanNameParser_Parser(${'name' . $i});
    ${'fname' . $i} = $parser->getFirst();
    ${'lname' . $i} = $parser->getLast();
  }  
else 
  { 
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?:

```
for ($i=2; $i <= 6; $i++)
{
if (!empty($_POST["name$i"])) {
    $name[$i] = ucwords(strtolower($_POST["name$i"]));
    $parser = new HumanNameParser_Parser($name[$i]);
    $fname[$i] = $parser->getFirst();
    $lname[$i] = $parser->getLast();
  }  
else 
  { 
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason the nameparser threw fatal errors using this way to define variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_POST['name'.$i]` to get that index. I would suggest something like this:

```
$people = array();
for( $i=2; $i<=6; $i++) {
    if( empty($_POST['name'.$i])) continue;
    $name = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['name'.$i]));
    $parser = new HumanNameParser_Parser($name);
    $people[$i] = array("first"=>$parser->getFirst(),"last"=>$parser->getLast());
}
```

This will result in a `$people` array, which is more usable than variable variables.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$name = array();
$fname = array();
$lname = array();
for ($i=2; $i <= 6; $i++)
{
    if (!empty($_POST['name_'.$i])) {
        $name[$i] = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['name_'.$i]));
        $parser = new HumanNameParser_Parser($name[$i]);
        $fname[$i] = $parser->getFirst();
        $lname[$i] = $parser->getLast();
    }  
    else 
    { 
        break;
    }
}
```